# iOS Launch Image without Storyboard or Images

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, launching-application

I am trying to programmatically set up a Launch Image without using storyboards or images.  I understand the two ways to set up a launch image are 'Launch Image Source(image)' & 'Launch Screen File (storyboard)'. Within storyboard it launches a UIViewController then you drag and drop items into the storyboard VC. I don't want to do any drag and drops is there a way to just do it all in code. I am completely want to avoid storyboards I don't want to have an empty one then it launches a simple VC then I go do designated VC I want simple VC then designated VC.  I am looking for an answer in Swift, I assume I would have to have code in AppDelegate but thats just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this. You either have to provide images or a storyboard file. You can choose to show a custom launch screen afterwards that is programmatic, but you cannot create the initial one programmatically.